# Hibernate How to create Restrictions parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I am very new to Hibernate and I am trying to understand how `Restriction` works with Criteria. I have a **ACCOUNTS** table with `id, user_id, date`. I want to grab **ACCOUNTS** table and filter out rows based on `id` which will be given to me.

I found that I could use `Restriction.eq("", Object)`. I was wondering if what I am trying to do is correct. Here is my code:

```
final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Accounts.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", accountId));
```

`accountId` is given accountId, which will be simple `String`.

`"id"` is defined in xml file like this:

```
<class name="com.xxxxxxx.Accounts" table="ACCOUNTS">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID"/>
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence_name">ACCOUNTS_ID_SEQ</param>
            <param name="sequence">ACCOUNTS_ID_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Would this work? I am not sure `accountId` will filter out the rows from crit. If it doesn't work, what is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is entirely correct. Is there any particular reason you are doubting yourself?

```
    public Accounts getById(final String id) {

        final Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Accounts.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        return (Accounts) cr.uniqueResult();
    }
```